# Retrieve the path of an opened file

Tags: python

I have such a file

```
In [24]: !cat test.py
print(f'The path is {__file__}')
```

run it to produce the module path

```
In [25]: run test.py
The path is /root/test.py
```

I could get its path from internal code.

Then I open another  `a_long_name_file.py`

```
In [43]:  f = open("a_long_name_file.md")

In [44]: cd .. #change the directory
/

In [45]: f.name
Out[45]: 'a_long_name_file.md'
```

If I change directories around couple of time and lost in the maze, and markdown file does not have internal code to help.

How could I get the path of "a_long_name_file.md"

Comment: Do you want an absolute path from file object i.e f?

Comment: No, abspath and realpath lead to wrong path, cos, I changed directory. @x899

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get path from open file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9542435/get-path-from-open-file-in-python)

Comment: @Sawajiri Why not store the path before you change directory?

Comment: I want to explore its extreme @RoadRunner

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Absolute path of a file object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2458676/absolute-path-of-a-file-object)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can: the `name` attribute relates to the name the file was opened with, which in case of a relative name, will remain relative.

You should either open the file with the full path, or cheat a bit:

```
In [1]: f = open("a_long_name_file.md")
In [2]: f.realpath = os.path.realpath(f.name)   # first thing after opening the file    
...
In [42]: cd ..
...
In [56]: f.realpath
```

---

NB: see [this question & answers on abspath and realpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37863476/why-would-one-use-both-os-path-abspath-and-os-path-realpath).